# How to reduce the size of the Apk file Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made and app in unity. And everything that i have put in, plugins,sprites,script,animations,sounds is about 100-110 Mb . But the size of the apk is 343 Mb. The app is made only for android. I am very puzzled to where are those extra 200Mb coming from .
Can someone please explain roughly from where that could've came and how could i reduce the apk size?

Comment: it did in a way, i shaved like 20% but i found something rather interesting and i don't know why it happens or how to fix it https://imgur.com/97NmC1t    https://imgur.com/zQrzdLt  . So this happens with most of the pictures that i have , they are 100-400kb size and become 4-8 Mb in unity  , this are the settings i have on each image https://imgur.com/RP5u7OY . Thanks for replying

Comment: This is normal, unity does use compressiion like JPEG or PNG, but other formats that the graphic card can read very fast, e.g. ETC or even uncompressed. You can read more about it here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/texture-compression-formats.html